# Problem on stem base of tomatoes and peppers

Tags: diagnosis, plant-care, vegetables

I'm a beginner gardener growing tomatoes and peppers from seed for the first time. I need some help diagnosing a problem on the base of the stem of most of my plants.

I've been watering my plants once a day during the last month and a half.
I started watering on top and then switch to bottom watering (I provably over did it).

[image]

I've checked the root systems on one that recently snapped and it just looks really healthy so doesn't seem to be root rot.

To my newbie eye it seems I have some brown fungus on top of the soil and it's just eating the stem.

Any ideas of what I may be facing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic example of damping off. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping_off

This process probably began when your seedling was very young.

In general, young seedlings need very little water. You want to keep the soil moist but not saturated. When in doubt, don't water.

Answer (score 0):

This could be [collar rot](https://content.ces.ncsu.edu/collar-rot-and-alternaria-stem-canker-of-tomato). Overhead watering too much water are factors. It's fungal.

According to the link you can try to build up soil around the lesion early in the process. Alternatively, you could try to cut some way above the lesion and replant the top of the plant. You'll  find lot of materials online on how to grow from cuttings.

If it's fungal don't put any of it in the compost and disinfect your pots and tools.

Answer (score 0):

I would say cut worms. Usually they kill seedling and young plants by eating the stem at ground level. Try wrapping aluminum foil around the stem.